# Extension of generic type with upper bound in swift

Tags: generics, swift3, protocols

Here is the code:

```
// won't compile!
extension Array where Element: JsonSerializable : JsonSerializable {
    var JsonRepresentation: AnyObject {
        var representation = [AnyObject]()
        for obj in self {
            representation.append(obj.JsonRepresentation)
        }
        return representation as AnyObject
    }
}

protocol JsonRepresentable {
    var JsonRepresentation: AnyObject {get}
}

protocol JsonSerializable: JsonRepresentable {
}

extension JsonSerializable {
    var JsonRepresentation: AnyObject {
        var representation = [String: AnyObject]()
        for case let (label?, value) in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            switch value {
            case let value as JsonRepresentable:
                representation[label] = value.JsonRepresentation
            case let value as AnyObject:
                representation[label] = value as AnyObject
            default:
                break

            }
        }
        return representation as AnyObject
    }

    func toJson() -> String? {
        let representation = JsonRepresentation
//        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(representation) else {
//            return nil
//        }
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: representation, options: [.prettyPrinted])
            return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The gist is that I want an array of JsonSerializables to be also JsonSerializable. How can I achieve that?

Comment: why JsonSerializable : JsonSerializable Twice?

Comment: The first is for Element, the second is for Array<Element>.

Comment: The first is a type bound, the second means the protocol I want to implement.

Comment: "I want an array of JsonSerializables to be also JsonSerializable" - this will be possible once [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) is implemented.

Comment: Cool. Before that happens, is there a workaround?